# How Can I Add Time Format hh:mm.ss from an awk statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk, fedora

I am using awk to get all of the 7th field separated by a comma.

```
1,root,init,20,0.0,0.1,0:01.78
1008,root,migration/0,1,2.0,1.8,7:04.32
26542,peter.ca,top,20,1.9,0.1,5:42.78
18776,john.sel,awk,15,0.2,0.0,0:01.00
49841,murray.s,topsum,16,1.3,0.1,0:02.11
29806,peter.ca,bash,20,0.1,0.0,0:00.03
9845,murray.s,awk,18,0.5,0.2,0:14.01
6549,peter.ca,topsum,16,1.4,0.2,0:04.81
18746,john.sel,bash,20,0.1,0.0,0:00.50
24987,john.bel,who,20,3.0,1.1,0:00.01
5,root,watchdog/0,1,0.0,0.0,0:00.00
29874,murray.s,timeon,20,0.1,0.2,0:02.15


cat data.top | grep root | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $7 }'
```

Output:

```
0:01.78
7:04.32
0:00.00
```

I am trying to add these together (I am also assuming that the total will be less than 24 hours so that is not an issue).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F, '/root/{split($7, t, ":"); sum+=60*t[1]+t[2]}; END{print sum}' input.txt
426.1

$ date -ud @426.1 +%T.%N | sed 's/0*$//'
00:07:06.1
```

Comment: That `date` command doesn't work at all.  The `-d` option is to set the kernel's value for DST, according to the man page.

Comment: @Graham - that's because kev's answer assumes Linux, presumably Fedora.

Comment: Doh.  Should have read the tags.  I didn't realize it was a platform-specific solution.  :(

Comment: Doesn't that discard fractional seconds? It seems like the best output would be `7:06.1` (since that's the format used in the inputs), but failing that, at least `00:07:06.1`. (But the OP has already accepted your solution, so maybe I'm too demanding! :-P )

Comment: rukah you are right. I just realized that now. It is not formatting the time properly.

Comment: date -ud @$total +%H:%M:%S:%N works but gives me too many zeros

Comment: You can use `sed` to get rid of trailing zeros.